# How to make a silverlight button respond only to mouse

Tags: silverlight, events, button, keyboard

I am using a toggle button, and I want it to only change its state due to mouse click. The default behavior is that if the focus is on the button, then the user may press "space" or "enter" to "click" it. I want to cancel this, but to still allow the button to respond to mouse click as usual (by triggering the click event).

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could set the [IsTabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property to false in which case you won't be able to focus the button and therefore it won't be able to respond to the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but that's not what I am trying to achieve here. I Do want the button to get focus, and I Do want the user to be able to press enter, I just don't want the button to be clicked as a result. I want to give the enter key a different behavior. The problem is that the button does not even generate KeyDown and KeyUp when Enter or Space are being pressed (it does for all other keys).

Comment: Then I believe the only way would be to derive from the Button class, override the OnKeyDown and not call the base implementation. The ButtonBase class overrides the OnKeyDown|Up methods and responds to the keys there.

Comment: @AndrewS, sounds like a good try to me. You could also do the same thing with a Behavior, then apply it in XAML.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this with a behavior since you need to be using a derived class. It would be nice if the Keyboard.AcceptsReturn property were public since that is what the ButtonBase class looks at to determine if it should eat the enter key - ButtonBase sets this to true in its ctor but CheckBox/RadioButton set it back to false.

Comment: hmmm - Andrew, you opened my eyes to something I was not aware of - can you expand a little about the AcceptsReturn. Does it allow the button to get focus?

Comment: @AndrewS, you were right a behavior didn't work. I tried applying a behavior to a ToggleButton and overriding the OnKeyUp/OnKeyDown event but it didn't catch the enter or space. They must not count as a key pressed event?

Comment: The button's OnKeyDown|Up is invoked before the instance event is raised so it is already handled. As for the AcceptsReturn it is an internal DependencyProperty that SL uses. I don't think there is any way to get to it. Personally I would just make the button IsTabStop false. So the only way to click the button is with the mouse. You could then add some other means (e.g. shortcut, menu, etc.) of invoking the same action via the keyboard to ensure 508/accessibility compliance.

Comment: AndrewS, the problem is that I DO want the button to catch focus, (also using tab). I need the user to be able to focus on it. When the user presses Enter I want to run some logic that decides if to click the button or not, while clicking it with the mouse yields different results. I know it's not traditional but I am not exactly using the button as a "button" but I still need a component that has the click event... Anyway, thnx a lot for the help.

Comment: So then the only option you have is to derive from Button as I mentioned in one of my earlier replies and override OnKeyDown|OnKeyUp and handle however you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a Behavior as I suggested in my common on AndrewS's post, but found that the KeyDown event didn't capture the space or enter event. You could capture the event at a higher level and cancel it if it is the space or enter key.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel KeyUp="sp_KeyUp">
  <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" content="toggle me" width="120" height="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
public void sp_KeyUp(object sender, KeyBoardEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
  {
    e.Handled = true; // this should cancel the event
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Aligned, but wont the sp_KeyUp routine only be called AFTER the button has already caught and responded to the key press? which means that canceling if wont prevent the button from getting the key press. 
Also - If the button traps the event, why would the container get it in the first place? It wont even bubble to the container...

Or am I wrong? :-)

Comment: I tried it out (in code and not just my head) and you're right. I was mixing it up with Tunneling events (PreviewXXX) in WPF, which you can't even do in Silverlight. Thanks for the correction :). After that attempt I'm thinking AndrewS has the correct answer.